# Undefined json data while using response.status react native

Tags: json, react-native, response, fetch-api

while using response status and response json data, only getting response status. 
responseText returns undefined.Code as follow

```
fetch('http://mysite/check.json')
    .then((response) => {
      response.json();
      this.setState({
       xstatus: response.status
     });
      console.log("status_return:",this.state.xstatus);
    })
   .then((responseText) => {
     this.setState({
      xtest: responseText
    });
     console.log("return-------",this.state.xtest);

   })
```

how to get both status & json data?

Comment: Did you try calling this API using Postman and are you getting the response status and response text in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that worked

```
fetch('http://mysite/check.json')
.then(response =>  response.json().then(data => ({status: response.status,body:data})))
.then(responseText => {
  this.setState({
   xtest: responseText
 });

  console.log("return-------",this.state.xtest);
```

Now i got status as well as data..